# Automapper pass ForMember(s) as argument

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there a way I can do something like this?

```
public void CreateMap<T, I>(??? ForMember)
{
  Mapper.CreateMap<T, I>().ForMember(ForMember);
}
```

I'm just trying to pass the ForMember as an argument a method that I can then attach to the Map.

Comment: I think you have to pass *two* parameters to .ForMember method. How will you call your method?

Comment: I guess I would call it with the required parameter to add Formember.  I think this is exactly the question I am struggling with.

Comment: There are two required parameters for ForMember, how do you expect to pass only one?

Comment: The question is based on a lack of knowledge on how to do this in the first place.  What I'm looking for I guess, is a means to add ForMember(s) to a Mapping.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the point of doing that. Why don't you just call the ForMember method? Like: `.ForMember(destination => destination.Property, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.SourceProperty))` ?

Comment: @thepirat000: If you read the question again, OP is asking how to add `ForMember()` to a mapping. Obviously if he wanted to call the `ForMember()` method he would. If you're unable to understand the question you shouldn't be trying to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible way to do it: given two classes

```
internal class ExampleClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class OtherExampleClass
{
    public string OtherName { get; set; }
}
```

Define the following function

```
 private static void CreateMap<From, To>
                              (Expression<Func<From, object>> FromExpression,
                              Expression<Func<To, object>> ToExpression)
 {
     Mapper.CreateMap<From, To>()
     .ForMember(ToExpression, opt => opt.MapFrom(FromExpression));
 }
```

And call it by passing the lambdas directly:

```
CreateMap<ExampleClass, OtherExampleClass>(fromClass => fromClass.Name, toClass => toClass.OtherName);
```

The `IMappingExpression` (the type returned from the `ForMember` method) is not something that you should use. It holds configuration and chaining methods but i don't think it is supposed to come from the outside. With a brief survey of the code i couldn't find any point at which you could add `IMappingExpression` so using the two lambdas will be your best bet imo